# Objective-C class methods returning parent class objects

Tags: objective-c, subclass, uibezierpath, subclassing

I'm trying to add a property to `UIBezierPath`. So I created a subclass called `JWBezierPath`. I wanted to have all the class method shorthands also with number parameter, so I created the methods:

```
+ (JWBezierPath *)bezierPathWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    JWBezierPath *path = [self bezierPath];
    [path setColor:color];
    return path;
}
```

The problem is, that `[self bezierPath]` does return an instance of `UIBezierPath` instead of my subclass. I also tried using concrete class: `[JWBezierPath bezierPath]`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show me your .h file

Comment: What kind of property do you want to add to `UIBezierPath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not implement `+bezierPath` method in your class then superclass implementation will be called that will create instance of UIBezierPath, not JWBezierPath.

In theory it is possible for factory methods in base class to create instances even if those methods won't be overridden, e.g. consider 2 options for factory method in BaseClass:

```
// Will create instance of child class even if method won't be overriden
+ (instancetype) someObject {
   return [self new];
}
```

vs

```
// Will always create instance of base class
+ (BaseClass*) someObject {
   return [BaseClass new];
}
```

However considering `+bezierPath` declaration (`+(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath`) and your evidence UIBezierPath class is not implemented that way and you have to implement `+bezierPath` method in your cub class

Comment: See my comment on Arkadiusz Holkos answer

Answer (score 1):

`bezierPath` is defined as:

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
```

so you might want to use:

```
JWBezierPath *path = [[self alloc] init];
```

instead.

Comment: Then I would have to get the source code of `UIBezierPath`. Because I don't know what happens in methods like `bezierPathForRect:` for example.

Comment: @Julian: Apple declared the return types of the class methods as `(UIBezierPath *)`, because they probably don't want anyone to override them. However, you should be able to simulate them with instance methods, such as: `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`, etc. You haven't said what kind of property you want to add. Maybe there's a better approach than inheriting from `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: I want to add a `color` parameter (like my example method shows). I could also make a category and work with runtime…

Comment: Why can't you use `UIColor`'s instance methods `setStroke` and `setFill`?

Comment: This is what I'm planning to do. But I have to associate a color with a path to transport the instance through the application. Another way would be an array with dictionaries, but this is a bit too less transparent for me. Now I created a category with `obc/runtime.`